# How do I evaluate "If" statement inside PlotLabel?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, gui-construction

I have an experimental function that is dependent on x and y [f(x,y)=Sin(ax/by)]. I am trying to make a 3D plot of f using the manipulate function so that I can easily input measured values of parameter f and h; where a and b are determined by f and h. The problem I have is that three conditions related to a and b hold important information for this experiment and I want the condition tested (according to the input values of f and h) and the result (severe, mild or normal) printed as PlotLabel. I have tried several options but I have not succeeded thus far.
1. Whenever I use on If statement testing one of the condition, I dont get any result at all.
2. However, when I added the other two, the code actually tested the correct condition according to the values I have in the input field but instead of putting the results directly above the plot as intended, it gives it as a new output field.

I would be very glad and grateful for your kind suggestions and recommendations. Many thanks!

My code:

```
Manipulate[
With[{a = (f + h) /(f*h) , b = f/(f*h) }, 
Plot3D[(Sin[(a*x)/(b*y)]) , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Row[{"a = ", a, " m", Spacer[8], "|", Spacer[9], "b = ", b, " m", 
  "|", Spacer[9], If[(a) > (4*b), Print[mild]], 
  If[(a) = (4*b), Print[normal]], 
  If[(a) < (4*b), Print[severe]]}]]], {{f, 1, "1st constant"}, 1, 
5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{h, 1, "2nd constant"}, 1, 5, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Drop the `Print` and note the difference between `=` and `==` (please see the documentation).

Comment: @Szabolcs, many thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Szabolcs, removing `Print` and changing `If[(a) = (4*b)` to `If[(a) == (4*b)` fixes the issue you were seeing:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{a = (f + h)/(f*h), b = f/(f*h)}, 
  Plot3D[(Sin[(a*x)/(b*y)]), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLabel ->
    Row[{"a = ", a, " m", Spacer[8], "|", Spacer[9], "b = ", b, " m", 
      "|", Spacer[9], If[(a) > (4*b), mild], If[(a) == (4*b), normal],
       If[(a) < (4*b), severe]}]]], {{f, 1, "1st constant"}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{h, 1, "2nd constant"}, 1, 5, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

1. [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) does not do what you think it does. It's unnecessary for the simple string concatenation you were doing, and more useful (along with `Echo`) for things like trying to track the internal state of a long-running function.
2. You made a simple mistake with `=` vs `==`. `=` is used to set values, while `==` is used to check equality. You can find out the details by evaluating `?=` and `?==` in Input cells in your notebook.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Many thanks!